# jquery json to select issues

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I'm having the below output from an ajax script:

```
{"DATA":[{"COUNTRYCODE":"1","DESCRIPTION":"USA","COUNTRYID":"211"},   {"COUNTRYCODE":"1","DESCRIPTION":"Canada","COUNTRYID":"37"},{"COUNTRYCODE":"1","DESCRIPTION":"Dominican Republic","COUNTRYID":"224"},
```

I am trying to populate a select menu with info from this JSON data:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">
$.getJSON(
        'getcountries.php',
        function(data) {
            var items = [];
            $('#country').append(data);

            $.each(data['DATA'], function(key, val) {
                    $.each(val, function(key, value) {
                            console.log(value);
                    });
            });
    }
    );
```

Issue with it is that the `$('#country').append(data)`  (or `append(data['DATA']`) always returns error "*Value does not implement interface Node.*"

Could anyone point out how I could get the specific JSON data I have into the select script?

Comment: Try $.each(data.DATA, ...

Comment: `$('#country').append(data)` won't work because `data` is an object, not a DOM element.  What do you expect that line to do?  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 4):

`.append()` only accepts HTML string, DOM Element, or jQuery Object

See: http://api.jquery.com/append/

I assume this is the result you actually want.

```
var data = {"DATA":[{"COUNTRYCODE":"1","DESCRIPTION":"USA","COUNTRYID":"211"},{"COUNTRYCODE":"1","DESCRIPTION":"Canada","COUNTRYID":"37"},{"COUNTRYCODE":"1","DESCRIPTION":"Dominican Republic","COUNTRYID":"224"}]};

var $select = $('#country').empty();

$select.append(
    data.DATA.map(function (el, i) {
        return $('<option>')
            .val(el.COUNTRYID)
            .text(el.DESCRIPTION)
            .data('DATA', el); // in case you also want to access its COUNTRYCODE
    })
);
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/terryyounghk/ZshG4/

Answer (score 1):

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/q5Q3d/

```
var a = {
    "DATA":[
        {"COUNTRYCODE":"1","DESCRIPTION":"USA","COUNTRYID":"211"},   
        {"COUNTRYCODE":"1","DESCRIPTION":"Canada","COUNTRYID":"37"},
        {"COUNTRYCODE":"1","DESCRIPTION":"Dominican Republic","COUNTRYID":"224"}
    ]
}

$.each(a.DATA, function(idx, val){
    var option = "<option value='" + val.COUNTRYID + "'>" + val.DESCRIPTION + "</option>";
    $('select').append(option);
});
```